# Tesseract for iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, tesseract

I now have the following problem and hope one of you can help me!
I have now Intergrated the new framework of Tesseract in my project and it worked very well the last 2 months . Now I wanted to continue to work on my app and all of a sudden I have been getting a error warning.
This :

```
DATAPATH / var/mobile/Applications/A5A474B0-53E8-4C16-87CD-DE23B9CA1173/Documents/tessdata
Error opening datafile / var/mobile/Applications/A5A474B0-53E8-4C16-87CD-DE23B9CA1173/Documents/tessdata/deu.traineddata
Please make sure the environment variable is set TESSDATA_PREFIX to the parent directory of your " tessdata " directory .
Failed loading language ' eng '
Error opening datafile / var/mobile/Applications/A5A474B0-53E8-4C16-87CD-DE23B9CA1173/Documents/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the environment variable is set TESSDATA_PREFIX to the parent directory of your " tessdata " directory .
Failed loading language ' tight '
Tesseract could not load any languages ​​!
```

How can it be that I can not find any more languages ​​it! I have not changed anything . It's all still the same ! I hope someone can help me to solve the problem quickly!

Comment: I can see a space between the leading '/' and 'var' in the file path. That must be an error but no idea howvto track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your document folder does not contain language file. You need to save language file in Document folder before initialise Tesseract. Please see my answer for similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299571/tesseract-running-error-on-xcode/21300448?noredirect=1#comment32104807_21300448)