# Tesseract running error on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tesseract

I have been testing Tesseract on Xcode.I followed instructions from Visit http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/ .But the problem is that when i run the program i get the following errors on console:

```
Error opening data file /Users/mdriduanulislam/Library/Application Support/iPhone 
Simulator/7.0/Applications/0ABCEAB3-3793-44C9-8914-
A99BB6B4EF9F/Documents/tessdata/eng.traineddata

Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory
of your "tessdata" directory.

Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!`
```

I have 1 problem which was been asked on StackOveflow but the answer was not satisfactory.Can someone please tell me why the problem is happening and the possible solution for the problem please.I'm eagerly waiting for right answer please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because your document folder does not contain language file. Use the code below to save language file which added in bundle to document folder. call this method before you initiate tesseract **Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"eng"];**

```
- (void)storeLanguageFile {

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/tessdata/eng.traineddata"];
        if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/tessdata/eng.traineddata"]];
            NSError *error;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/tessdata"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
            [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        }
}

- (NSString *)scanImage:(UIImage *)image {

        Tesseract *tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"/tessdata" language:@"eng"];

        [tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
        [tesseract setVariableValue:@".,:;'" forKey:@"tessedit_char_blacklist"];

        if (image) {
            [tesseract setImage:image];
            [tesseract setRect:CGRectMake(0, point.y- 25, image.size.width, 50)];
            [tesseract recognize];
            return [tesseract recognizedText];
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have tried with the method you mentioned.But its showing on the console different types of strings(numbers) instead of original texts on the image.Like "1111111111115111111116 601515011111
151  11111 11 11111111
11010110911110
5018118 51181111310175
11110111113130 11
13151185151 511117111116
14112311511111011121121111111
50110 01141 1111121
111011275311 0111 011 011151"
What can i do now?

Comment: Md.RiduanulIslam So error fixed and now the problem with detected text. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes.It is.Please tell me how can i fix it.

Comment: use the below code to set which all characters tesseract should detect and avoid.         
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
        [tesseract setVariableValue:@".,:;'" forKey:@"tessedit_char_blacklist"];

Comment: Great!Thank you so much! Its working! Anyway, Can i have your email or Skype ID please?

Comment: If i apply this method for other languages will it work?

Comment: You can download language files from https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list . I didnt tried other languages but I hope same procedure will work with other languages too.

Comment: this is not working for another languages just working for english please help

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430947/add-any-traineddata-file-in-tesseract-and-use-in-ios/21575881#21575881

Comment: Hi,I had tried to detect bangla font using tessaract.The detection is arround 30-40% accurate which is so poor.I guess it should be 70-80% accurate.Do i need to set anything for reading that font(e.g. Bangla)? Please tell me if you have any suggestions. @Vaisakh

Comment: @Vaisakh followed the same procedure as you said but still getting the error 

TesSample[3941:60b] Exists
Error opening data file /Users/user0001/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/36BCF2F6-280E-43D6-975F-4A294456DF80/TesSample.app/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching for the solution, none of the proposed solutions worked for me because I am using objective C++ in xcode. But after tons of experimentations, for anyone that still need this solved, the solution is a 1-liner (if ure using TessBaseAPI), before api.init(...) add 
G8Tesseract *tesseract = [[G8Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
This magically gets rid of the TESSDATA_PREFIX error

Answer (score 0):

After adding TESSDATA_PREFIX to your system variables, try restarting your PC. I'm running Windows 10 and that's what fixed this error for me.