# Add any traineddata file in tesseract and use in IOS

Tags: ios, tesseract

I am able to compile the ENGLISH version which is already in sample for tesseract but not able to add other language like ara.traineddata.

I am doing like

```
 Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"ara+eng"];
```

And it is recogninzing ENGLISH but for ara it is giving error

```
Error opening data file /Users/harshthakur/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/3B0A1909-E1BA-45E9-99A0-FDEAB2CFF4E0/Documents/tessdata/ara.traineddata
```

Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'ara'

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the document folder does not have language file. Copy ara.traineddata file to your bundle and use this code to save your language file in document folder. Then try again. It will work fine.

```
- (void)storeLanguageFile {

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/tessdata/ara.traineddata"];
        if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/tessdata/ara.traineddata"]];
            NSError *error;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/tessdata"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
            [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        }
}
```

Comment: @Vaisakh I can not find the language file can you please indicate where that file should be???

Comment: I am using latest tesseract-ocr-ios by gali8

Answer (score 1):

Have  a look here ,maybe it will be helpful to you .

[Tesseract](https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios)

here you can

```
   -setLanguage:

  - (BOOL)setLanguage:(NSString *)language
```

Override the language defined with -initWithDataPath:language:.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `ara.cube.*` files also.

Flipping the order of the languages could improve recognition rates, once you get it to run.